# Adding Admob to a Visual Studio 2015 cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

Having great difficulty adding AdMob to an existing Visual Studio Cordova project. Seems every plugin I try fails for various reasons. Either the compile fails, or perhaps it does a "require", which my app is not using Node at all. The google docs say that their Android app creation environs is required - but is that true?

If anyone has successfully added AdMod to their existing Visual Studio 2015 project (all client side), could you please share specific steps for doing so?
TIA

Comment: Could you please post the error message that you got when you adding the plugin or run the project with the plugin?

Comment: No error - but if you are looking to implement this, it is imperative that everything be loaded in the correct order. I finally got it .The only combo that worked for me was following exactly the code found in the cordova-admob git hub example.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to implement this, it is imperative that everything be loaded in the correct order. I finally got it .The only combo that worked for me was following exactly the code found in the cordova-admob git hub example.

Comment: I'm too having problems, with VS 2017 in my case. If you got it working, could you point me to the exact location of the example you mention? And what is the correct order? Thanks